# Two columns in the second column in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word document and the page layout is set for two columns. In the middle of the page in the second column, I want to have a section that will be again separated in two columns. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirement, I think we can **insert Table** as a workaround. In the middle of the second column or first column, insert a two columns table. Copy and paste the content to two cells. Then set no Border for it. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I just faked it. I used tab break in the middle of the second column and also faked the bullet symbol (ALT + 7) which I needed.

Comment: You could have inserted a two-column table into that space.

Comment: I don’t understand how this “answer” addresses the question.